# eBay authorization over browser Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, ebay-api

Recently I start to program app (android platform) which should create auctions on eBay, whole thing is for my school project.
in case of authenticate the user must generate a link with sessionid and runame only then user will get authorization token.

**My problem is:** 
 When I launch new browserIntent which authenticate URL I can't "go back" to my menu (I can use back button but it is not very user friendly), is there any way to fire up WEBbrowser witch "go back to menu" button at the bottom ?

Do you guys have any other idea how can fire up browser but keep "control" over the app ?

small agenda:

runame - application ID
authenticate URL - address where user put his username and password (only way to authenticate user)

P.S. I can not use eBay SDK because android do not support SOAP.

Comment: Hey Molu I am doing the same and creating a similar application but I am not even able to login using native or Web view, can you help me out that how did you got login, did you use an activity or web view in android application, can you share the api you are using for login with all parameters required.

Comment: Hey, It was a bit long time ago but i remember that i wrote some code in PHP which send the auth request to the eBay API and than Send it back to me. Communication between my PHP and my phone was established on base of HTTP (kind of REST). To sending the request from my phone i used ASYNC task.  Hope that helped, let me know if you have some more specific question.